# Apache Flink - Filter Performance Tips

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say you are working on a big flink project. And also you are `keyBy` the **client ip addresses** of your customers.

And realized that you are going to filter the same things in the different code places like that:

```java
public void calculationOne(){
   kafkaSource.filter(isContainsSmthA).keyBy(clientip).process(processA).sink(...);
}
```

```java
public void calculationTwo(){
   kafkaSource.filter(isContainsSmthA).keyBy(clientip).process(processB).sink(...);
}
```

And assumed that they are many `kafkaSource.filter(isContainsSmthA)..`

Now this structure leads to performance issue in the flink?

If I did something like the below, would be much better?

```java
public Stream filteredA(){
   return kafkaSource.filter(isContainsSmthA);
```

```java
public void calculationOne(){
   filteredA().keyBy(clientip).process(processA).sink(...);
}
```

```java
public void calculationTwo(){
   filteredA().keyBy(clientip).process(processB).sink(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on how it should behave operationally.

The first way is a more friendly to the Kafka cluster: all records are read once. The filter itself is a very cheap operation, so you don't need to worry to much about it. However, the big downside of this approach is that if one calculations is much slower than the others, it will slow them down. If you do not process historic events, it shouldn't matter as you'd size your application cluster to keep up with all events anyways. Another current downside is that if you have a failure in `calculationTwo` also tasks in `calculationOne` are restarted. The community is actively working to mitigate that though.

The second way would allow only the affected source -> ... -> sink subtopology to be restarted. So if you expect frequent restarts or need to guarantee certain SLAs, this approach is better. An extension is to actually have separate Flink applications for each of these pipelines. You can share the same jar, but use different arguments to select the correct pipeline on submission. This approach also makes updating of applications much easier as you would only experience downtime for the pipeline that you actually modify.

Comment: What you were saying, was really interesting and new for me. For **case 1**: how records are processed then? for example, filtered recordA from kafka will pass through processA, processB ... process C, kind of chain of responsibility pattern.  For **case 2**: how records will be duplicated? Because we have a continuous flow. That would be awesome to see some implementation (in flink github repo) how **case 1** works.

Answer (score 0):

I might do something like below, where a simple wrapper operator can run data through two different functions, and generate two side outputs.

```java
SingleOutputStreamOperator comboResults = kafkaSource
    .filter(isContainsSmthA)
    .keyBy(clientip)
    .process(new MyWrapperFunction(processA, processB));
    
comboResults
    .getSideOutput(processATag)
    .sink(...);

comboResults
    .getSideOutput(processBTag)
    .sink(...);
```

Though I don't know how that compares with what Arvid suggested.